# Delete and Show FileField via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, yii

I would like to delete an image and re-show the uploaded field at update view (yii).

1. there is an image which is uploaded.
2. when the user delete this image.
3. at that time the image will delete and the upload `$form->filefield` will appear at the image place.

This is view

```
<div id="forAjaxRefresh"><img src="<?php echo $file; ?>" width="150px" /></div>

<?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink('clickMe', array('ajax'), array('update'=>'#forAjaxRefresh'));?>
```

This is controller

```
public function actionAjax()
    {
        $model=new CompanyLicense('search');
        //$this->render('update', array('model'=>$model,'test'=>'test'), false, true);
        //echo "$form->labelEx($model,'file_path');
        //$form->fileField($model,'file_path', array('class'=>'input-file')); 
        //$form->error($model,'file_path'); ";
        //echo "$form->labelEx($model,'file_path')";

        echo 'OK';
    }
```

When I tried like it. It was showing the 'OK' at . But I want to show the upload file field at . How could I do? Please help me.

===============+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++====================================

latest mvc

model nothing change

Controller

```
public function actionAjax($id)
    {
        $model=new CompanyLicense();
        //$this->render('uploadfield', array());
        //echo "$form->labelEx($model,'file_path');
        //$form->fileField($model,'file_path', array('class'=>'input-file')); 
        //$form->error($model,'file_path'); ";
        //echo "$form->labelEx($model,'file_path')";


        echo $this->renderPartial('uploadfield',array('model'=>$model),false,true);

        /*
        $model=Company::model()->findByPk($_GET['id']);

        if($model){
            $file = '/images/'. $model->id . '/'. $model->file_path;
            unlink(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../..'.$file);
        }
        <br />
*/


    }
```

view (_form.php)

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'company-license-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
    'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
)); ?>

    <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

    <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'company_id'); ?>
        <?php
            $records = Company::model()->findAll();
            $list = CHtml::listData($records, 'id', 'name');            
        ?>     
        <?php echo $form->dropDownList($model,'company_id', $list, array('prompt'=>'Please select a Company')); ?>

        <?php echo $form->error($model,'company_id'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'license_no'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'license_no',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'license_no'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'license_name'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'license_name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>200)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'license_name'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'annualfee'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'annualfee',array('size'=>10,'maxlength'=>10)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'annualfee'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'expire_date'); ?>
        <?php 
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDatePicker', array(
                'name'=>'expire_date',      
                'model'=>$model,
                'value' => $model->expire_date, 
                'options'=>array(
                    'showAnim'=>'fold',
                    'dateFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',

                ),
                'htmlOptions'=>array(
                    'style'=>'height:20px;'
                ),
            ));
            ?>
        <p> Expire Date must be greater than Current Date.</p>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'expire_date'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'notification_days'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'notification_days'); ?><p> Notification Days must be between 7 and 90.</p>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'notification_days'); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'description'); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'description',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'description'); ?>
    </div>


    <div class="row" id="file_upload">
    <?php
        $file = '/images/'. $model->id . '/'. $model->file_path;

        if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../..'.$file)){
            echo '<img src="http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . $file.'" width="150px" />' ;

        }else{
        ?>
            <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'file_path'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'file_path', array('class'=>'input-file')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'file_path'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
    </div>      

    <div id="forAjaxRefresh"><img src="http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . $file; ?>" width="150px" /></div>
    <div class="row buttons">
        <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
    </div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->


<?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink('remove', array('ajax'), array('update'=>'#forAjaxRefresh')); ?>


<?php
echo CHtml::ajaxLink( 'delete',  array( 'companylicense/ajax',  'id'=>$model->id), array('type'=> 'GET', 'update' => '#forAjaxRefresh') );
?>

<?php echo CHtml::ajaxLink('remove2', array('url'=>array('companylicense/ajax', 'id'=>$model->id),
), array('update'=>'#forAjaxRefresh')); ?>
```

view (uploadfield.php)

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id'=>'company-license-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
        'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
    )); ?>
<?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'file_path'); ?>
<?php echo $form->fileField($model,'file_path', array('class'=>'input-file')); ?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'file_path'); ?>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: were you able to make it work?

Comment: Yes, my last ans can make it and I replace your echo CHtml::Tag into my controller. Both solutions are working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite it is not healthy attitude to spoon feed someone, but it seems like you are having great deal of trouble. see its very very simple and you have adopted complex approach.

follow the steps and you are good to go.

`View`

```
 <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'full_version'); ?>                
 <?php if($model->full_version == '')
           echo $form->filefield($model,'full_version',array('style'=>'width:100%;')); 
       else
       {
           echo '<div id="file"><b>'.$model->full_version.'</b> '.CHtml::AjaxLink('Delete',CController::createUrl('removeFinalVersion',array('id'=>$model->id)),array('update'=>'#file')).'</div>';
       }?>
<?php echo $form->error($model,'full_version'); ?>
```

Now what we have to do is replace the `file` `Div` with the file upload think. If you have to upload more fields than file field then you can use separate file and render it in controller and echo. but for this demo I am considering returning only one item only.

so when Ajax request is made things come down to `actionRemoveFinalVersion` where all the talking needs to be done and filefield has to be returned

it looks something like this

```
public function actionRemoveFinalVersion($id)
    {
            $user = Products::model()->findByPk($id);
            if($user === null)
                yii::app()->end();
            $user->full_version = '';
            $user->save();
            //return CHtml::activeFileField($model,'full_version',array('style'=>'width:100%;'));
            echo CHtml::Tag('input',
                    array(
                        'style'=>"width:100%;",
                        'name'=>"Products[full_version]" ,
                        'id'=>"Products_full_version",
                        'type'=>"file"));
    }
```

concentrate on `name` and `id` of the returned `filefield`. it needs to be precise so that `validation` can occur. `I am using this and it works`. so should yours if you do correct things.

Also when playing with AJAX do use Firebug tool in firefox and similar in Chrome

Comment: Thank your for your quick reply. Yes, your understanding is correct what I want. but you know, I'm very newbie for yii. Could you tell me more detail? thx

Comment: I told ya the main scheme you give it a try and tell me :) if it works or not

Comment: Afnan, this is the main schema I knew it. The file uploading is OK, no problem. AjaxLink is fine and it is return 'OK' from controller. and I can delete img when clicking the ajaxlink. But my problem is I don't know how to return the fileuploadfield to view. So pls.

Comment: rather than returning filefield If i were you i would keep `fileField` there all the time and on success change the `display style to block `

Comment: Thank you for ur ans, Afnan. But I am sorry bec it isn't what my PM want. It is only switching within 2 div tag. Can you help me with another idea?

Comment: Afnan, I followed your latest edit. I created new file for upload field (uploadfield.php). in the uploadfield.php, need to add <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
 'id'=>'company-license-form',
 'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
 'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'),
)); ?>

if I did like that the ajax is working correctly, but when I select new img and click update. the selected file did not save and upload. how should I do? if I remove the widget, there is an error "Undefined variable: form" at firebug. need help !!

Comment: problem is you are inserting a new form inplace of forAjaxRefresh.

Answer (score 0):

I can solved it. :D :D

Model nothing change

View (_form.php)

```
<div class="row" id="file_upload">
    <?php
        if ($model->id){
            $file = '/images/'. $model->id . '/'. $model->file_path;
            echo '<div id="forAjaxRefresh">';
            echo '<img src="http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . $file.'" width="150px" />' ;
            echo CHtml::ajaxLink('remove', array('delimg', 'id'=>$model->id), array('update'=>'#forAjaxRefresh'));
            echo '</div>';

        }else{
        ?>
            <div class="row">
            <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'file_path'); ?>
            <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'file_path', array('class'=>'input-file')); ?>
            <?php echo $form->error($model,'file_path'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
    </div>
```

view (uploadfield.php)

```
<?php echo CHtml::label('File', 'Application_word_report'); ?> 
<?php echo CHtml::fileField('CompanyLicense[file_path]', ''); ?>
```

Controller

```
public function actionDelimg()
{
    $model=CompanyLicense::model()->findByPk($_GET['id']);

    $file = '/images/'. $model->id . '/'. $model->file_path;
    if(file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..'.$file))
        unlink(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../..'.$file);

    $this->renderPartial('uploadfield',array('model'=>$model),false,true);
}

public function actionUpdate($id)
    {
        $model=$this->loadModel($id);
        if(isset($_POST['CompanyLicense']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['CompanyLicense'];
            $currentTime = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', time());                             
            $model->updated = $currentTime; 
            $model->active = 1; 

            $model->file_path=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'file_path');

            $folder = Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/';
                        if($model->save())
                        {
                $model->file_path->saveAs($folder. $model->id . "/" . $model->file_path);
                // redirect to success page

                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
                        }  
        }

        $this->render('update',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```